# different scale for outcome(y-axis) in logistic regression plot

Tags: r, logistic-regression

For Plotting logistic regression with multiple predictors I used a library(ggeffects) in R. To make logistic regression plots for all variables I wrote the below code which `glm.fit` is an output of `glm()` function:

`plts = lapply(names(coefficients(glm.fit))[-1],function(i){   return(plot(ggpredict(glm.fit,i))) })`

Finally, I used the below function
wrap_plots(plts ,ncol = 2, nrow = 4)

and I get the below plot for my 7 predictor variables
[image]

as you see, the Y-axis for **WBC** is between 0 and 100% but for **RBC**, it is between 0 and 60%. I would appreciate it if anybody could explain to me how I Y-axis for all my predictors will be between 0 and 100%.

Best regards,

Comment: Do you want to know why the y values are always between 0 and 1 (or 0 and 100%)? These are probabilities, which are always within the 0-1 range

Comment: @GuedesBF I'm pretty sure OP wants the y limits to be 0 and 1 for every subplot, not shrunk down depending on range of each subplot.

Comment: I suspected that, Gregor, just want to make sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a summary of what I understand is wrapped up in your code:

- You're using the function `glm` in the `stats` package to fit a model. `stats` is a base R package.
- You're using the function `ggpredict` in the `ggeffects` package to construct predictions.
- Calling `plot` on the output of `ggpredict` means you're using a plot-method from the `ggeffects` package.
- Finally, you're using the function `wrap_plots` from the `patchwork` package to assemble your final figure.

```
plts = lapply(names(coefficients(glm.fit))[-1],function(i){
   return(plot(ggpredict(glm.fit,i))) 
})

wrap_plots(plts ,ncol = 2, nrow = 4)
```

My understanding of your question is that you're (1) wondering why the y-axis on your plots varies, and (2) asking how to produce plots with the same y-axis scale of 0-100%.

1. The plots are being produced by this function https://strengejacke.github.io/ggeffects/reference/plot.html. In your code, it's generating a single plot per coefficient which means that each plot's y-axis scale is set independently to the range of data in that plot.
2. To produce plots with the same y-axis scale using your current plotting approach, you will want to add `limits=c(0,1)` to the `plot` function.

```
plts = lapply(names(coefficients(glm.fit))[-1],function(i){
   return(plot(ggpredict(glm.fit,i),limits = c(0,1))) 
})

wrap_plots(plts ,ncol = 2, nrow = 4)
```

Here's a reproducible example for a GLM with 2 predictors. First, here's the example with the compressed y-axis scale.

```
# load libraries
library(ggeffects)
library(patchwork)

# read data from
# https://environmentalcomputing.net/statistics/glms/glm-1/
crabs <- read.csv("https://environmentalcomputing.net/datasets/Crabs.csv")

# fit model
glm.fit <- glm(CrabPres ~ Time + Dist, family = binomial, data = crabs)

# predict the response for each coefficient
# then plot the predictions 
plts = lapply(names(coefficients(glm.fit))[-1],function(i){
  return(plot(ggpredict(glm.fit,i))) 
})

# use patchwork to arrange plots
wrap_plots(plts ,ncol = 2, nrow = 1)
```

[image]

Now here's the example with the new, 0-100% y-axis scale:

```
# load libraries
library(ggeffects)
library(patchwork)

# read data from
# https://environmentalcomputing.net/statistics/glms/glm-1/
crabs <- read.csv("https://environmentalcomputing.net/datasets/Crabs.csv")

# fit model
glm.fit <- glm(CrabPres ~ Time + Dist, family = binomial, data = crabs)

# predict the response for each coefficient
# then plot the predictions 
plts = lapply(names(coefficients(glm.fit))[-1],function(i){
  return(plot(ggpredict(glm.fit,i),limits=c(0,1)) 
})

# use patchwork to arrange plots
wrap_plots(plts ,ncol = 2, nrow = 1)
```

[image]